# Is there any way to find the scaling coefficient for a CGDisplay?

Tags: macos, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm currently doing some tests to see if my app runs correctly on Retina Macs. I have installed Quartz Debug for this purpose and I'm currently running a scaled mode. My screen mode is now 960x540 but of course the physical size of the monitor is still Full HD, i.e. 1920x1080 pixels.

When querying the monitor database using `CGGetActiveDisplayList()` and then using `CGDisplayBounds()` on the individual monitors in the list, the returned monitor size is 960x540. This is what I expected because `CGDisplayBounds()` is said to use the global display coordinate space, not pixels.

To my surprise, however, `CGDisplayPixelsWide()` and `CGDisplayPixelsHigh()` also return 960x540, although they're explicitly said to return pixels so I'd expect them to return 1920x1080 instead. But they don't.

This leaves me wondering how can I retrieve the real physical resolution of the monitor instead of the scaled mode using the `CGDisplay` APIs, i.e. 1920x1080 instead of 960x540 in my case? Is there any way to get the scaling coefficient for a `CGDisplay` so that I can compute the real physical resolution on my own?

I know I can get this scaling coefficient using the `backingScaleFactor` method but this is only possible for `NSScreen`, how can I get the scaling coefficient for a `CGDisplay`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to examine the *mode* of the display, not just the display itself. Use `CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode()` and then `CGDisplayModeGetPixelWidth()` and `CGDisplayModeGetPixelHeight()`. These last two are relatively newer functions and the documentation primarily exists in the headers.

And, of course, don't forget to `CGDisplayModeRelease()` the mode object.

Comment: Here's a follow up that is related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42024942/1197719

Answer (score 0):

From Ken's answer it is not obvious how you find the native mode(s). To do this, call `CGDisplayModeGetIOFlags` and choose from the modes that have the `kDisplayModeNativeFlag` set (see `IOKit/IOGraphicsTypes.h`, the value is 0x02000000).

```
const int kFlagNativeMode = 0x2000000;  // see IOGraphicsTypes.h
const CGFloat kNoSize = 100000.0;

NSScreen *screen = NSScreen.mainScreen;    
NSDictionary *desc = screen.deviceDescription;
unsigned int displayID = [[desc objectForKey:@"NSScreenNumber"] unsignedIntValue];
CGSize displaySizeMM = CGDisplayScreenSize(displayID);
CGSize nativeSize = CGSizeMake(kNoSize, kNoSize);
CFStringRef keys[1] = { kCGDisplayShowDuplicateLowResolutionModes };
CFBooleanRef values[1] = { kCFBooleanTrue };
CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void**)keys, (const void**)values, 1, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks );
CFArrayRef modes = CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes(displayID, options);
int n = CFArrayGetCount(modes);
for (int i = 0;  i < n;  i++) {
    CGDisplayModeRef mode = (CGDisplayModeRef) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(modes, i);
    if (CGDisplayModeGetIOFlags(mode) & kFlagNativeMode) {
        int w = CGDisplayModeGetWidth(mode);
        // We get both high resolution (screen.backingScaleFactor > 1)
        // and the "low" resolution, in CGFloat units. Since screen.frame
        // is CGFloat units, we want the lowest native resolution.
        if (w < nativeSize.width) {
            nativeSize.width = w;
            nativeSize.height = CGDisplayModeGetHeight(mode);
        }
    }
    // printf("mode: %dx%d %f dpi 0x%x\n", (int)CGDisplayModeGetWidth(mode), (int)CGDisplayModeGetHeight(mode), CGDisplayModeGetWidth(mode) / displaySizeMM.width * 25.4, CGDisplayModeGetIOFlags(mode));
}
if (nativeSize.width == kNoSize) {
    nativeSize = screen.frame.size;
}
CFRelease(modes);
CFRelease(options);

float scaleFactor = screen.frame.size.width / nativeSize.width;
```